# Exporting array in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: export, google-earth-engine

I got a list of values and I could print them to the Console. It looks like this:

```js
{
    "chlor_a": 0.12718113166405862
  },
  {
    "chlor_a": 0.37072379355468843
  },
```

How can I export it to my Drive account in csv format?

This is the code so far:

```js
var bo=ee.FeatureCollection('users/broadsky2008/Border');

var chla = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI")
.filterDate('2012-7-04', '2018-1-25')
.select('chlor_a');

var reduceR = function(image) {
  return image.set('number',image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: bo.geometry(),
 }));
};

// Map the function over the collection and display the result.
var mChla=chla.map(reduceR);


// Get a list of the numbers.
var numberList = mChla.aggregate_array('number');

print(numberList);
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument(s) to `set()` should be either a key, value pair or a dictionary.  Here is your (corrected) example, assuming you've got a geometry called `geometry` defined somewhere:

```js
var chla = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI")
  .filterDate('2018-1-04', '2018-1-25')
  .select('chlor_a');

var reduceR = function(image) {
  return image.set(image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: geometry,
 }));
};

var mChla=chla.map(reduceR);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(mChla), 
  description: 'foo', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'foo', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV', 
  selectors: ['chlor_a']
});
```